# Boost spirit is too greedy

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm in between a deep admiration about boost::spirit and eternal frustration not to understand it ;)

I have problems with strings that are too greedy and therefore it doesn't match. Below a minimal example that doesn't parse as the txt rule eats up end.

More information about what i'd like to do : the goal is to parse some pseudo-SQL and I skip whitespaces. In a statement like

```
select foo.id, bar.id from foo, baz
```

I need to treat `from` as a special keyword. The rule is something like

```
"select" >> txt % ',' >> "from" >> txt % ','
```

but it obviously doesn't work at it sees  `bar.id from foo` as one item.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main(int, char**) {
    auto txt = +(qi::char_("a-zA-Z_"));
    auto rule = qi::lit("Hello") >> txt % ',' >> "end";
    std::string str = "HelloFoo,Moo,Bazend";
    std::string::iterator begin = str.begin();
    if (qi::parse(begin, str.end(), rule))
        std::cout << "Match !" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "No match :'(" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my version, with changes marked:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main(int, char**) {
  auto txt = qi::lexeme[+(qi::char_("a-zA-Z_"))];     // CHANGE: avoid eating spaces
  auto rule = qi::lit("Hello") >> txt % ',' >> "end";
  std::string str = "Hello Foo, Moo, Baz end";        // CHANGE: re-introduce spaces
  std::string::iterator begin = str.begin();
  if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, str.end(), rule, qi::ascii::space)) {          // CHANGE: used phrase_parser with a skipper
    std::cout << "Match !" << std::endl << "Remainder (should be empty): '"; // CHANGE: show if we parsed the whole string and not just a prefix
    std::copy(begin, str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout << "'" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "No match :'(" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This compiles and runs with GCC 4.4.3 and Boost 1.4something; output:

```
Match !
Remainder (should be empty): ''
```

By using `lexeme`, you can avoid eating spaces conditionally, so that `txt` matches up to a word boundary only. This yields the desired result: because `"Baz"` is not followed by a comma, and `txt` doesn't eat spaces, we never accidentally consume `"end"`.

Anyway, I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for -- in particular, is `str` missing spaces as an illustrative example, or are you somehow forced to use this (spaceless) format?

Side note: if you want to make sure that you've parsed the entire string, add a check to see if `begin == str.end()`. As stated, your code will report a match even if only a non-empty prefix of `str` was parsed.

**Update:** Added suffix printing.

Comment: Thank you ! This lexeme was the thing I was missing. You were completly right to add spaces (I left them out in the example trying to have something minimal, but I guess it was more confusing than anything)